# Django - custom validation for different users

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a date time field called bk_time. Now, I would like to write custom validation for bk_time based on **different users**.

For example, I have users `Staff_A`, `Staff_B` and `Superuser`:

1. `Staff_A` can only set the time = Mon-Fri 9am-12am
2. `Staff_B` can only set the time = Monday only
3. `Superuser` no limitation

I have referred [Django Doc Validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/). But it seems not working for multiple validation

I have tried to write `save_formset`[Django Doc Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).But it seems not able to raise ValidationError

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Location', max_length=100)

class Room(models.Model):
    room_label = models.CharField('Room Lebel', max_length=100)
    bk_time= models.DateTimeField('Booking Time')
```

admin.py

```
class RoomInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Room
    extra = 0

class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name']
    fields = ('name')
    inlines = [RoomInline]
```

If this is relevant, I'm using Django 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to come on the form validation, and not on the field validation. This is because your validation depends on two independent fields.

In particular, this is very similar to an authentication: your validation depends on the user and on another field. Take a look how Django implements its authentication (from `django.contrib.auth`):

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                           password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
                )
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['inactive'],
                    code='inactive',
                )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

In your case, you want to raise a `ValidationError` on a given constraint, and return cleaned_data otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment
I get the idea to implement my objective